# What is the magnification of this microscope image?

Tags: microscopy

I mistakenly forgot to write down the magnification of this lobster egg image.

I do know that each division on the graticule is 20 microns, as I calibrated it using another duplicate graticule: the actual sizes of the graticules are 5mm long with 100 divisions, and I lined it up so that the installed graticule in the eyepiece spanned only 40 of the 100 divisions of the graticule on the base plate. I believe this meant the installed eyepiece graticules divisions represented 20 microns.

I can see that the eye spot on the egg is 29 divisions, so it is 580 microns long.

Is it possible to determine the magnification with this information?

[image]

Comment: If you know the size (check the literature to see if your calculated size is close to expected for the egg), you generally don't need the magnification - you simply put a scale bar on the image representing sensible units.

Comment: Hi @bob1, thanks for your response but i need to report the magnification in this case. Would you know how?

Comment: It's impossible to say from an image on the internet - images scale with different display formats/qualities. If you have the original image and can display it at the 1:1 scale, then you can do an approximation. The internets tell me that a lobster egg is ~1/16" or 1.58 mm in diameter, so you could work it out that way.

Comment: How about taking another image of another lobster egg (or even the same egg)?  Try to find a setting/magnification where the same zoom of the resultant image with the same image resolution will give you a similar visual representation.